# How to find the list of universities running a specific program?

Tags: graduate-school, university, undergraduate, united-states, united-kingdom

Is there any way/resource for finding the list of universities offering a specific degree?

I want to find which universities have a specific program (both undergraduate and graduate).

My target is the US and UK universities, but other countries are also useful (though, I think it is difficult to search because of different terminologies in different languages for a discipline).

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 for a full explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UK graduate schools are officially ranked through [Research Assessment Exercise](http://www.rae.ac.uk/) (being currently phased out to be replaced by [Research Excellence Framework](http://www.ref.ac.uk/)), so you can get a full list of programs that are of any worth [here](http://www.rae.ac.uk/results/selectUOA.aspx).

In the US, rankings are produced from time to time by the National Research Council. [The most recent set](http://sites.nationalacademies.org/PGA/Resdoc/PGA_044749) is from 2009. The methodology and reporting format are beyond weird, but at least the list of programs is useful (albeit difficult to navigate in the Excel file format; I found my area, statistics, under "Physical sciences", for instance, which is a very distant shot). The [1995 rankings](http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~jnewton/nrc_rankings/nrc1.html) were done with involvement of real statisticians, so I trust them better.

Answer (score 0):

First you should decide what is your major. For universities in USA you can use websites like [US News](http://www.usnews.com/education) or like [BigFuture](https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/college-search). You can google for finding university offering specific courses and degrees about UK. I believe for US universities US News is the best website.